# How to solve: $\int \frac{dx}{2x^2 + 9x+ 9\sqrt{x^2+ 3x+ 2}}\; ?$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> Integrate: $$\int \frac{dx}{(2x^2 + 9x+ 9)\sqrt{x^2+ 3x+ 2}}$$

Could anyone tell me how to do it? I've broken the term under root into two linear factors; but then don't know how to proceed.

Could anyone please help me?

I don't want complete solution; just a hint on how to proceed after I break that into linear factors.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only ask for a hint, here is one:

Instead of factoring the polynomial *inside* the square root, try to do the same with the polynomial *outside* the square root. Then do partial fraction decomposition on that part to split the integral in two. Once that is done, you make the substitutions that fits to the different terms. Ask for further steps if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; I'll let you know my work. +1